# Linode and namecheap configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, linode, namecheap

I have namecheap account which I use for managing my DNS settings, I just leased linode.com VPS and have a small configuration set inside it , I am not able to find out any guides to point domains to my linode server, can somebody help me out

Comment: Namecheap doesn't have documentation?  Like this? http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/544/51/how-do-i-set-up-host-records-for-a-domain-when-i-use-free-dns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. In your namecheap account you are only setting nameserver records, which should be pointed to the linode namservers. At linode, log in and make master dns records for your domain with their dns tools. Give it a few hours to propagate and you should be in business. (You can get the nameservers you need from linode as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Linode VPS gives you a dedicated IP address. Go to [namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/myaccount/login-only.aspx?ReturnUrl=/myaccount/domain-list.asp), login, go to manage domain, domain control panel, and point your domain to the linode IP.